# Possible to develop "Windows Mobile 6.1" appl. with EVC4 (Embedded Visual C)?

Tags: windows-mobile-6, evc4

Is it possible to develop "Windows Mobile 6.1" appl. with EVC4 (Embedded Visual C++)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if your executables will run on Windows Mobile 6.1, the answer is yes.